# How can you find the number of occurrences of a particular character in a string using sql?

Tags: sql, string, search

How can you find the number of occurrences of a particular character in a string using sql?

Example: I want to find the number of times the letter ‘d’ appears in this string.

```
declare @string varchar(100)
select @string = 'sfdasadhfasjfdlsajflsadsadsdadsa'
```

Comment: Which database? MySQL perhaps?

Comment: Please give this a more descriptive title, you'll see better results.

Comment: The answer is probably going to be database-specific, so please tell everyone what database you are using.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Here you go:

```
declare @string varchar(100)
select @string = 'sfdasadhfasjfdlsajflsadsadsdadsa'
SELECT LEN(@string) - LEN(REPLACE(@string, 'd', '')) AS D_Count
```

Comment: Cute, I was thinking of iterating with charindex, I like this much better.

Comment: I agree with vfilby and can confirm this code works in SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Comment: I am a MySql user. and definately not a guru. What would be the equiv of D_Count in MySQL?

Comment: D_Count is just an alias for the column. i don't know how you set that in MySql

Comment: You should also divide by the length of what you're looking for. This script works because 'd' is only one character long. If you were looking for 'as', you'd have to divide the answer by two.

Comment: Sybase ASE (15.7 at least) requires str_replace instead of replace, and null instead of '' for the replacement character.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to make it a little more general, you should divide by the length of the thing you're looking for. Like this:

```
declare @searchstring varchar(10);
set @searchstring = 'Rob';

select original_string, 
(len(orginal_string) - len(replace(original_string, @searchstring, '')) 
   / len(@searchstring)
from someTable;
```

This is because each time you find 'Rob', you remove three characters. So when you remove six characters, you've found 'Rob' twice.

Comment: This figures you're querying a table called `someTable` which has a column called `original_string`. And the principle will work in any database, you just need to find the equivalent functions.

Answer (score 2):

For all you Sybase ASE 15 dinosaurs our there, you will need to replace '' with null, i.e.

```
SELECT LEN(@string) - LEN(REPLACE(@string, 'd', null)) AS D_Count
```

Comment: As someone dealing with an old Sybase installation, many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In SQl Server if @string = 'sfdasa       ddd'
function LEN fails to count trailing white spaces.
Solution to LEN's issue is in
[LEN function not including trailing spaces in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025585/len-function-not-including-trailing-spaces-in-sql-server)

Comment: While interesting, this does not actually answer the question. Perhaps it could be a comment for another answer.