# Look for trailing spaces in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'd like to know how I can identify trailing spaces in a table. I'm using SQL Server 2008 and create the following table as a test

```
CREATE TABLE  first_test_name
   ( 
   firstName varchar(255)
    )
```

And then inserted a record like this:

```
insert into first_test_name (firstName)
values('Bob')
```

I then tried inserting a space and then adding a new record like this:

```
insert into first_test_name (firstName)
values('Bob ') -- just 1 space
```

And for a 3rd time,

```
insert into first_test_name (firstName)
values('Bob  ')   -- two spaces used this time.
```

Now if I query for for 'Bob' (no spaces), I still get a count of 3.
My query was:

```
select count(*) from first_test_name WHERE firstName = 'Bob'
```

Shouldn't the answer have been 1?

Also, I used `sp_help` on this table and the value for "Trim Trailing Blanks" is set to no.

So why am I getting a count of 3? I was expecting just 1.

On a related note, if I search using this query

```
select * from first_test_name
where firstName like '% '
```

I then get the right answer of two rows found.

So just to reiterate, the question is why I get a count of 3 when searching for 'Bob'.
Also, what does "Trim Trailing Blanks" mean in this case?

Comment: Take a look at this link http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/02/15/ansi_padding-and-trailing-spaces-in-sql-server/ to understand how SQL Server compare strings with spaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why I get a count of 3 when searching for 'Bob'?

[SQL Server ignores trailing spaces in most string comparisons.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9456/empty-strings-why-or-when-is-equal-to/9457#9457)

> Also, what does "Trim Trailing Blanks" mean in this case?

This tells you the [`ANSI_PADDING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) option set when the table was created.

> How can I identify those two with 1 or 2 trailing spaces?

Here's one way.

```
SELECT *
FROM first_test_name 
WHERE firstName LIKE 'Bob '
```

And to find ones with no trailing space

```
SELECT *
FROM first_test_name 
WHERE firstName LIKE 'Bob' AND firstName NOT LIKE 'Bob '
```

Comment: thanks for answer and the link (which was actually quite helpful).

Comment: What are you checking for in this part of your query?
 'Bob %[^ ]%'

Comment: @Ray - The first bit matched values beginning `Bob{space}` and can use an index to find matching records. The second bit eliminates any matches that begin with `Bob{space}` but have following non space characters such as `Bob Hope`. On reflection none of that was needed though. `LIKE 'Bob '` works fine.

Comment: I had a feeling that that's what it was looking for, but thank you for confirming this. Yes, like 'BOB ' is all I really need for the data I'm looking for. Thanks again, @Martin.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server will expand strings with whitespace during comparisons.

This is what I would do:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM first_test_name
WHERE REPLACE(firstName, ' ', '_') = 'Bob'
```

Comment: I like this answer better. For me, I did something similar in the where clause: where replace(relationship, 'S ', 'S_') = 'S_'. The select statement was spot on trying to find the trailing whitespace when I did the same in the select: select relationship, replace(relationship, 'S ', 'S_') from X

Answer (score 2):

SELECT *
FROM USERS
WHERE DATALENGTH(Username) <> DATALENGTH(RTrim(Username))

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be to append something on the string.

```
declare @test table(
id varchar(4) not null,
firstname varchar(255) not null)

insert into @test values('1', 'Bob')
insert into @test values('2', 'Bob ')
insert into @test values('3', 'Bob  ')
insert into @test values('4', ' Bob')

select count((firstname + 'end')) from @test 
where (firstname + 'end') not like '% %'
```

The query will return a count of 1.

Answer (score 1):

A good clean way to do this would be to compare your original string against an Rtrim version of itself where they don't match e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM First_Test_Name
WHERE Firstname <> RTrim(Firstname)
```

This should return all records where Firstname has trailing spaces (I think ...)

Comment: That won't work because trailing spaces make no difference in `=` OR `<>` string comparisons.

Comment: Is the != option available in SQL-Server, or is that only Oracle, if so would that be any better?

Comment: It is available it doesn't behave any differently though. It still obeys the rules for comparison predicates listed here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626

Answer (score 0):

I was looking recently and couldn't find the answer to this. Thought I'd share since coming across one.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14188944/1953837

LEN trims trailing whitespaces by default. Using the below they are moved to the front and then the field length is counted.

Hope this helps anyone searching in the future.

(LEN(REVERSE(FieldName))