# Length Issue in SQL Server while adding spaces in varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Problem**:

I have three variables `@str1`, `@str2`, `@str3`.
So when I add spaces at start of the variable, It gives me right length, but when I add spaces at last it gives me wrong result.

**Solution**:

To avoid this behavior I could use `trim` the variable before checking the length of that variable.

**Question**:

why it happens anb What is the benefit of doing this(trimming spaces from right side, not left)?

```
 declare @str1 varchar(30), @str2 varchar(30), @str3 varchar(30)
    SET @str1 = ' kratika,vikas,kritika'
    SET @str2 = 'kratika,vikas,kritika '
    SET @str3 = 'kratika,vikas,kritika'

PRINT LEN(@str1)
PRINT LEN(@str2)
PRINT LEN(@str3)
```

**Output**

```
    22
    21
    21
```

Please let me know if question is not clear.

Comment: This is a well know feature of SQL Server.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025585/len-function-not-including-trailing-spaces-in-sql-server

Comment: Check the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what it's [*documented*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190329.aspx) to do:

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.

, and,

> To return the number of bytes used to represent an expression, use the [`DATALENGTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173486.aspx) function.

There are a number of features in SQL which all treat trailing blank characters as somewhat special. For instance, the strings `'abc   '` and `'abc'` are considered to be equal because effectively, spaces are *added* to the shorter string before the comparison occurs.

---

If you want to determine the length of a string, *including* trailing blanks, then the obvious thing is to concatenate a single non-blank to the string passed to `LEN()` and then subtract one from the result.