# 1+1=3? Space characters in nvarchar variables and string lengths

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, nvarchar

I've just stumbled upon this:

Why doesn't the following code:

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(10) = N' '

PRINT CONCAT('#', @s, '#')
PRINT CONCAT('#', LEN(@s), '#')
```

result in either the output

```
##
#0#
```

or

```
# #
#1#
```

On a SQL Server 2017, however, this code produces the output

```
# #
#0#
```

Which seems contradictory to me.

Either the string has the length 0 and is '' or the length 1 and is ' '.

The whole thing becomes even stranger if you add the following code:

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(10) = N' '

PRINT CONCAT('#', @s, '#')
PRINT CONCAT('#', LEN(@s), '#')

DECLARE @l1 int = LEN(CONCAT('#', @s, '#'))

PRINT LEN(@s)
PRINT LEN('#')
PRINT @l1
```

Which outputs the following:

```
# #
#0#
0
1
3
```

So we have three substrings, one with length 0, two with length 1. The total string then has length 3? I'm confused.

If you fill @s with several spaces, it looks even more funny - e.g. 5 spaces results in this output:

```
#     #
#0#
0
1
7
```

So here's 1×0 + 2×1 even 7. I wish my bank would calculate my account balance like this.

Can someone explain to me what's going on?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: you will get related details here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025585/len-function-not-including-trailing-spaces-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression,
>   **excluding trailing spaces**.

So `LEN('          ')` = 0 (only spaces), but `LEN(' x')` = 2 (no trailing spaces).

> LEN excludes trailing spaces. If that is a problem, consider using the
>   [DATALENGTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (Transact-SQL) function which does not trim the string. If
>   processing a unicode string, DATALENGTH will return twice the number
>   of characters.

Comment: "If processing a unicode string, DATALENGTH will return twice the number of characters." This is not correct. DATALENGTH returns the number of octets (bytes) in a variable. On SQL Server `nvarchar` is a UTF-16 character string and due to Surrogate and Supplementary characters may take four or more bytes to describe single characters. Ref: [Surrogates and Supplementary Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/surrogates-and-supplementary-characters)