# SQL Right Function

Tags: sql

I receive UPC data from a customer as 13 digits but I only use the right 10 digits so I am trying to use Right(upc1,10) to get the data I want.  I am doing something wrong because I am only getting 7 digits.

```
select div,   upc1,   right(upc1,10) as upc,   len(upc1),   
       len(right(upc1,10))
from Custfile

div   upc1            upc       (No column name)    (No column name)
10    1001111090729   1090729       13              7
10    1004139005004   9005004       13              7
```

Since I was only getting 7, I tried asking for Right 13 instead of Right 7 and am getting 10 digits

```
select div, upc1, right(upc1,13) as upc, len(upc1), 
       len(right(upc1,13))
from Custfile

div   upc1            upc        (No column name)   (No column name)
10    1001111090729   1111090729    13             10
```

This give me what I want but I am sure I am missing something obvious. Would appreciate if someone could point out my error.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) What is the type of `upc1`?

Comment: What is returned when  Select '-->' + upc1 + '<--'   ?  Is upc1  char or varchar? What type is it?

Comment: This is clearly documented by Microsoft in MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329(SQL.90).aspx, which states LEN "returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks".     See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025585/len-function-not-including-trailing-spaces-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You would appear to have three invisible characters at the end of the UPC.  If these a trailing normal spaces, then `trim()` might help  or `replace()`.  That would look like:

```
right(replace(upc1, ' ', ''), 10)
```

This assumes the problem is trailing spaces.

Alternatively, use `substr()` or your database's equivalent:

```
substr(upc1, 4, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff and donPablo for your help.  There was something there beyond 13 digits that I could not see.