# SQL Server removing necessary whitespaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

I'm trying to add whitespaces to a column. However, the `SPACE` function is not working.

Example:

```
SELECT LEN(('ABC' + SPACE(10)))
```

Returns 3 instead 13.

This behavior also happens with the `REPLICATE` function.

Example:

```
REPLICATE(' ', 5)
```

Returns `''`

What I need:

```
REPLICATE(' ', 5)
```

Returns `'     '`

Editing:

This suggestion works, but it needs do add `:` to the string.

```
DECLARE @Test varchar(32); 

SELECT @Test = 'ABC' + SPACE(10); 
SELECT @Test + ':';
```

Returns `ABC          :`

I need `ABC`

```
--This table is in SQL Server
CREATE TABLE Iten
(
    Code varchar(35)
);

--This table is on DB2
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    code char(35),
    description varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO Iten VALUES ('ABC');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES ('ABC', 'My Test')

SELECT 
    Iten.Code, Product.description, 
    DATALENGTH(Iten.Code), 
    DATALENGTH(Product.code)
FROM
    Iten 
INNER JOIN 
    IBMServerD.DatabaseD.LDAT.Product AS Product ON Iten.Code = Product.code
```

This query returns no rows.

Because that, I need to fill spaces on the right to `Iten.Code`, but it does not respect it.

If both tables were in SQL Server, it would work fine.

Comment: If trailing whitespace is significant then it might be wise to use `varbinary` instead of `varchar` - assuming you don't need to perform string operations in SQL.

Comment: BTW, `LEN()` always ignores trailing whitespace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025585/len-function-not-including-trailing-spaces-in-sql-server

Comment: According to the documentation on [len()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) `Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing spaces.`

Comment: `DECLARE @Test varchar(32); SELECT @Test = 'ABC' + SPACE(10); SELECT @Test + ':';` works i.e. gives a string 14 chars long which appears to be what you want.

Comment: In this particular situation, I can't change field datatypes.

Comment: `REPLICATE(' ', 5)` does returns you 5 spaces. If can't use `len()` to determine the length as it ignore the trailing spaces

Comment: @JoséPauloR.deLima you don't need to add the colon to make the spaces stay there, my code illustrates that the spaces **are** there since `LEN` doesn't tell you. But they are there whether or not you add the colon - so don't add the colon.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for your answer. In fact, I'm trying to join a CHAR(35) with a VARCHAR(35). In order to match the join, I have to add whitespace. I cant' use TRIM on CHAR(35) because it's on AS400 server and it makes the query extremely slow.

Comment: @JoséPauloR.deLima so whats not working about what you are trying to do? Create a [mre] that demonstrates your actual issue.

Comment: [How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces-b62b1a2d-27d3-4260-216d-a605719003b0)

Comment: @DaleK I added an example. It's hard to emulate because it uses to differente databases.

Comment: @JoséPauloR.deLima its pretty important you include those sorts of details right from the start... how are you linking your databases?

Comment: @DaleK sorry for not posting from start.

I'm using IBM DB2 UDB for iSeries IBMDA400 OLE DB Provider on SQL Server Linked Servers.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the trailing space, as SQL Server will pad the `varchar` to match the `char`. Probably a different collation or weird characters. We need a [mcve]

Comment: @Charlieface if both tables were on SQL Server, it would work. It pads the ````char```` to match the ````varchar````. But as the ````char```` field is on DB2, it does not pad.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `trim` functions

```
SELECT Iten.Code, Product.description, DataLength(Iten.Code), 
       DataLength(Product.code)
  from Iten INNER JOIN IBMServerD.DatabaseD.LDAT.Product as Product
    ON ltrim(rtrim(Iten.Code)) = ltrim(rtrim(Product.code))
```

Comment: Using TRIM it works. However, the query turns out very slow. I probably will use this solution, but it's not efficient.

Comment: @JoséPauloR.deLima Yeah, this is one disadvantage. If problem is whitespaces in rigth side of Product.code, you could reduce it to `Iten.Code = rtrim(Product.code)`

Comment: @JoséPauloR.deLima Changing Sql Server `varchar(35)` to `char(35)` would be a problem? Or maybe `cast(Iten.Code as char(35))`

Comment: It would be an issue, I can't change the field. Also, I tried to cast the field as char(35) but it does not work either.

Answer (score -2):

```
'ABC' + REPLICATE(' ',10)
```

works

Comment: Trying on SQL Server 15.0.something gives my your result, SPACE(n) is always one space.

Comment: If you use ````LEN('ABC' + REPLICATE(' ', 10))```` it returns ````3````.


If you use ````DATALENGHT('ABC' + REPLICATE(' ', 10))```` it returns ````13````.


But I need to use ````'ABC' + REPLICATE(' ', 10)```` to join with a field. Then, it removes whitespace

Comment: `SPACE(n) is always one space` that is not true. Not sure how do you come to that conclusion

Comment: Right you are. SELECT LEN('ABC' + REPLICATE(' ',10) + '.') shows a length of 14. I don't like what the LEN function is doing.

Comment: @Squirrel - you are correct I was making a false observation assuming the LEN() function worked like I thought it did.

Answer (score -2):

```
SPACE(INTEGER) is working fine  
select LEN('abc'+SPACE(10))    `3`
```

`LEN()` function excludes trailing blanks/whitespaces

```
select DATALENGTH('abc'+SPACE(10))   `13`
```

using  `DATALENGTH()` give you `13`,  `DATALENGTH()` includes trailing blanks/whitespaces

Comment: That doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: I hope this address the question @DaleK

Comment: @zeeshan12396 unfortunatelly, this does not solve the issue.

Comment: rather then space everything is working fine , i have no idea why??