# How to find if there is only one hyphen in a column SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have a table '`customer`' like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+--------+
|                     Customer                     |   ID   |
+--------------------------------------------------+--------+
| OSHKOSH CORPORATION-17180                        | cust12 |
| L&T-IES-P&G KABUSHIKI KAISHA-4216                | cust13 |
| THE PROCTER-GAMBLE MANUFACTURING COMPANY-17214   | cust14 |
+--------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

I should get only one row since column customer has only one hyphen.

```
| OSHKOSH CORPORATION-17180                        | cust12 |
```

Comment: There's no direct function for this, but you can do it with a replace and len.  Similar kind of question is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287373/how-can-you-find-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-particular-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without considering the performance, below sql can achieve this.

```
select *
from customer
where (len(Customer) - len(replace(Customer, '-', ''))) = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from customer
where customer like '%-%'
and customer not like '%-%-%'
```

The first check is for at least one `-`, the second is for not at least two. Combined it means exactly one.