# Is there any ways to count number of character in NVARCHAR column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I have `100001,100002,` stored in a `NVARCHAR` column.

I want to count the number of occurrences of `,` in this column.

Comment: `select len(col) - len(replace(col, ',', ''))`

Comment: @juergen d: Too bad; your comment would have been my answer :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Just as well you didn't answer as there are [plenty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789225/number-of-times-a-particular-character-appears-in-a-string) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287373/how-can-you-find-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-particular-character-in-a-string) [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738282/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-sql-varch) targets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select len('100001,100002,') - len(replace('100001,100002,',',',''))

returns 2

Comment: This was already written in the comments, what makes your answer better?

Comment: It's not.   I'm sure if you looked at the time stamp you'll see that we posted at virtually the same time.

Comment: 11 minute difference, but still. `2016-05-23 16:23:49Z` -> `2016-05-23 16:34:39Z`

Comment: I stand corrected.  I'll be more careful in the future.